# Python : Logging in module script to be called in another script

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, module

I have around 15 different python scripts for an application development, among of which 10 includes logging for debugging purposes. Now there is a main script say "hutextract.py" which is to run with a filename as an argument. Previously the log file name was fixed "test.log". Now I want to create the logging file with the same name as the input filename (except the extension). My "hutextract.py" code, where "randpage" and "mandate" are other python scripts :

```
from randpage import genrand
from mandatebase import formext
...# importing other scripts, functions
import logging

file_name=sys.argv[1]
def return_log_name():
    return ".".join(file_name.split("/")[-1].split(".")[:-1]) + ".log"

log_file_name = return_log_name()

logging.basicConfig(filename=log_file_name, level=logging.DEBUG, format="%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:%(message)s")
```

In randpage.py, mandatebase.py and other scripts, logging is also included there :

```
import logging
from hutextract import return_log_name
log_file_name = return_log_name()
logging.basicConfig(filename=log_file_name, level=logging.DEBUG, format="%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:%(message)s")
```

This creates an error which is obvious that when we try to run hutextract.py with argument which calls the other scripts (and their functions) which in return again summons return_log_name function from hutextract.py for logging purpose :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "hutextract.py", line 3, in <module>
    from randpage import genrand
 File "/home/src/randpage.py", line 3, in <module>
    from mandate_final import sigext
 File "/home/src/mandate_final.py", line 5, in <module>
    from hutextract import return_log_name
 File "/home/src/hutextract.py", line 3, in <module>
    from randpage import genrand
ImportError: cannot import name 'genrand'
```

How to do the logging inside all the module scripts to save the log file with same name as the input filename given as an argument?

Comment: You have a circular requirement; hutextract imports from randpage which imports from hutextract which ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you have provided is because of circular import. You may see this circle in the traceback `hutextract.py` - `randpage.py` - `mandate_final.py` - `hutextract.py`

Now to the logging. You should use `logging.basicConfig(...)` only once across multiple scripts (in the starting script) because this line of code modifies so-called root logger of the logging module. This root logger is created when you first import logging module and it is located in the global scope. So root logger is always available - just use it like `logging.debug('message')` where and when you need.